# System.out и System.in паралельно

Tags: java

Как можно параллельно использовать консоль, для вывода и для ввода данных.
запускаю в другом потоке с методом для получения данных из консоли, и в основном потоке вывод данных которые он может получить из сети. Но основной поток не выполняется пока я не прерву или не введу данные в консоль. Как можно использовать параллельно?

В отдельном потоке запускаю на считывание строки с консоли:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         try {
             Thread.sleep(10000);
             sendMessage("my sdf");
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
});
thread.run();
```

в основном потоке делаю запрос на сервер и жду ответа от сервера, когда он ответит(он может ответить и через минуту и сразу) я печатаю на консоль то что он мне ответил

```
System.out.println(request(address, json));
```

Comment: Либо у меня сильно отсвечивает лампа в мониторе, либо в вашем вопросе действительно нет кода, который вы мучаете

Comment: странно, вот такой код http://pastebin.com/r0dGDDjN успешно читает и выводит под windows 7 и в eclipse и в cmd.exe.

Comment: что-то я не пойму, а что вы хотите получить? если консоль одна, то тут действительно тут либо ждать ответа, либо считаете ерунду. Разве не проще переопределить System.out ?

Comment: @svetlana-popova что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: @JTan я хочу сказать, что если у вас один поток печатает консоль, допустим, "output info", а другой пытается считать, допустим, "input info" из ТОЙ ЖЕ САМОЙ консоли, то без ожидания потока вы считаете что-то вроде "put info ouinput info". Это ж основы многопоточности. Хотите, чтобы потоки работали одновременно - доверьте каждому свой объект, переопределив System.setOut и System.setIn. Или вопрос не об этом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никогда так не делайте:

```
thread.run();
```

Для запуска потока предназначен метод `start`:

```
thread.start();
```

Comment: а в чем там разница, разве это не запустит в итоге метод run?

Comment: запустит, но он запустит его *в другом потоке*! А вы запускаете его в том же самом потоке, то есть реально нового потока вы не создаете.